# thermal equilibrium in deep space

Tags: thermal-radiation, cosmic-microwave-background

Imagine an object- say, a sooty asteroid- in deep space, far enough from any star to receive only negligible radiation from it. We make it sooty so as to make it a good absorber of radiant energy and a good emitter as well, so that if it is heated, it will approximate a black body. It is bathed in the 2.7K cosmic microwave background and contains no internal heat sources.

In the absence of other influences, will it eventually come into thermal equilibrium with the 2.7K background, or will it be too poorly coupled with the CMB for this to happen? If our asteroid is not in fact striving towards equilibrium with the CMB, then what are the other mechanisms present in this context which would prevent that equilibrium from being reached?